# How to create two storyboards for Universal keyboard extension? iPhone and iPad

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, custom-keyboard, ios-keyboard-extension

I want to create Custom Keyboard extension.

My custom keyboard extension have two different layouts for iPhone and iPad.

I want to create two storyboards for the iPhone and iPad respectively but the problem is i can't give two reference for iPhone and iPad for keyboard in plist file of extension.

In extension there is no class like appdelegate to initiate a different storyboards with viewcontrollers.

Do anyone have idea how can i use two different storyboards for keyboard extension?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try to implement them in one storyboard with different size classes

Comment: Size classes is the way to go. Watch this stream from apple: https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/design/812/

Comment: Use autolayout.